# In Typescript, can a type get the private keys/members of a class?

Tags: typescript

I have a class:

```ts
import someOutsideComponent, { ComplicatedValue } from 'some-library';

export interface MutatedValue {
  // ...
}

export default class MyClass {
  method1() {
    return this.method2();
  }

  private async method2() {
    const value = await someOutsideComponent.doStuff();
    return this.doComplicatedLogic(value);
  }

  private doComplicatedLogic(value: ComplicatedValue): MutatedValue {
    const mutated = // mutate value
    return mutated;
  }
}
```

I want to test `MyClass.doComplicatedLogic`, and for sufficiently good reasons, I don't want to mock `someOutsideComponent` and simply want to pass in test values.

My current method is to do something like

```ts
import MyClass from './my-class';

interface MyClassPrivateMembers {
  method2: MyClass['method2'];
  doComplicatedLogic: MyClass['doComplicatedLogic'];
}

type WithPrivate<C, P> = { [key in keyof C]: C[key]; } & P;

type MyClassWithPrivate = WithPrivate<MyClass, MyClassPrivateMembers>;

describe('doComplicatedLogic()', () => {
  let myClass = new MyClass() as unknown as MyClassWithPrivate;

  it('returns the expected value', () => {
    expect(myClass.doComplicatedLogic({ /* ... */ })).toMatchObject({ /* ... */ });
  });
});
```

This works fine.  However, I'd like not to define `MyClassPrivateMembers` statically, as I'd rather not include a line per method.

Is it possible to get the private keys/members of a class with a type?

Comment: What testing framework are you using? If jest you might consider looking at [jest.spyOn](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname). It seems to me you'd like to test `method1` and inside it there are other utility functions invoked. [Also good lecture](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/100959/how-do-you-unit-test-private-methods)

Comment: I have tests for `method1`, and I use `spyOn` in many cases, but `method1` has a very complicated workflow, and I need to be able to test some private methods directly.

Comment: You can't do this afaik, see [microsoft/TypeScript#22677](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22677).  It's possible you want to make these methods public but export the type as an `Omit`ted type.  If you want me to elaborate I might be able to write up an answer

Comment: @jcalz nah, I know what you mean.  Thanks!